# How to park a car in the simulation of vehicular network using omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

in my simulation, I need to park a car in the parking, and when the car is out of the parking, it transfers their information to the rest of the cars inside the parking.Therefore, when the vehicle is parked in the parking ,its communication with the outside or with the interior of the parking should not be interrupted.

i am using omnetpp-5.0, sumo-0.25.0 and veins-veins-4.4. I tried to apply changes to the base veins, but I did not get the result.

How can I park a car without interrupting communication with the outside and inside of the parking ?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in Veins so I can only speak for the sumo side. you can simply add a stop to the vehicle route and flag it is a parking like that:

```
<vehicle id="1" depart="0">
    <route edges="edge1 edge2"/>
    <stop lane="edge2_0" endPos="100" duration="100" parking="true"/>
</vehicle>
```

If this is not working because parking removes the vehicle from the network and thus may disable the communication because there is no reliable position anymore, then create a separate street in your network:

```
<vehicle id="1" depart="0">
    <route edges="edge1 edge2a parking edge2b"/>
    <stop lane="parking_0" endPos="100" duration="100"/>
</vehicle>
```

where "parking" has at least one lane more then edge2 such that vehicles can overtake. (I wrote the example from memory without testing so there maybe errors in it.)

Answer (score 1):

The below excerpt may help, as it demonstrates a vehicle at a temporary stop (simulating parking). For details look into TraCIMobility.cc in veins

```
void TraCIMobility::handleSelfMsg(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg == startAccidentMsg) {
        commandSetSpeed(0);
        simtime_t accidentDuration = par("accidentDuration");
        scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentDuration, stopAccidentMsg);
        accidentCount--;
    }
    else if (msg == stopAccidentMsg) {
        commandSetSpeed(-1);
        if (accidentCount > 0) {
            simtime_t accidentInterval = par("accidentInterval");
            scheduleAt(simTime() + accidentInterval, startAccidentMsg);
        }
    }
}
```